# How can i use same data in two different php pages?

Tags: php

I want to use my data (for example a session variable) in two different php pages...  I want to show same data on action.php to action2.php... Want to link the data to different pages. Like, two different pages but only one data...  I'm having some problems on doing this. Thanks for your advices!

I have two different php pages. My first php page have a form but the form itself actions to the same page that it is in. Other php page (action2.php) is the page which i want to show the same data... comes from to the first page's submit...

Hopefully i will get some help...

And sorry for my bad English...

Comment: All session data in PHP can be accessed using the `$_SESSION` super-global, so long as you call `session_start()` on each page you wish to use it.

Comment: But i want to link the first php page's data to the second php page's data that comes from first page's submit. But i want this without linking them via forming... I want a different way because my first page already has a form that is built results on same page. How is this possible?

Comment: How about GET variables?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the POST/GET method to send data to your action2.php file. EX:

```
<form action="action2.php" method="post"> // or GET
<input name ="data" value="data" />
<input name = "data2" value="data2" />
</form>
```

Then in your action2.php file :

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["data"]) && isset($_GET["data2"]))
    {
        $data = $_GET["data"];
        $data2 = $_GET["data2"];
    }
?>
```